# What resource is my Lambda function exhausting?

Tags: python, multithreading, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The following AWS Lambda function uses multi-threading to read 10,000 small objects of about 40KB each from AWS DynamoDB.

```py
import boto3
import threading
import math
import json

class DynamoDB:
    def __init__(self, table_name):
        self.client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
        self.table_name = table_name
    
    # Batch-read
    def read(self, keys):
        batch_keys = {
            self.table_name: {'Keys': [{'content_id': {'S': id}} for id in keys]}}
        return self.client.batch_get_item(RequestItems=batch_keys)

dynamodb = DynamoDB("mytable")
    
def read_vectors(keys):
    batch_size = 100
    n_batches = math.ceil(len(keys)/batch_size)
    for i in range(n_batches):
        my_keys = keys[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size]
        dynamodb.read(my_keys)

def concurrent_reads(keys, n_threads):
    threads = []
    keys_per_thread = math.ceil(len(keys)/n_threads)
    for i in range(n_threads):
        my_keys = keys[i * keys_per_thread : (i + 1) * keys_per_thread]
        thread = threading.Thread(target=read_vectors, args=(my_keys,))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    keys = [f"vectors/{content_id}" for content_id in range(10000)]
    concurrent_reads(keys, 5) # 5 threads
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Here are the time measurements:

```
Threads      Time, sec
1            10.5
2             7.1
3             5.5
4             5.2
5             5.4
```

I get similar performance with 2048 MB of RAM and with 10240 MB of RAM. Given that all objects add up to 400 MB and Lambda runs in the same region as DynamoDB, I am definitely not saturating the network bandwidth (especially with 10240 MB, which should give ~25 GiB/s).

What resource is my Lambda exhausting that prevents it from scaling?

P.S. The question at re:Post: https://repost.aws/questions/QUoFkFRrJ-TaSjU2wbS38XqQ/what-resource-is-my-lambda-function-exhausting

Comment: 1. The network isn't multithreaded. 2. The database's disk isn't multithreaded. 3. Beyond a certain point the database server isn't multithreaded. 4. There is no particular reason to expect more threads to reduce elapsed time in the first place: it is always a question of balance.

Comment: @user207421 AWS DynamoDB certainly can serve at much greater scales than my humble 10,000 objects. So, I certainly don't accept reasons 2 and 3. I don't understand reason 4. As for reason 1, the network is not multithreaded, but it has enough capacity.

Comment: I would look at read capacity on your DynamoDB table.

Comment: @kdgregory That does not seem to be the problem. I was able to call 10 of these AWS Lambda functions, each doing 1000 objects, in parallel from another AWS Lambda function and they performed well.

Comment: Hmm, and what else have you done that you're not telling us?

Comment: Since it's Python code, I suppose it could be the GIL. That depends on how much pure Python code is executed around the DynamoDB calls. Have you run on your local machine? If yes, how does the performance compare? If you get similar performance on your local machine, then I believe there are web pages that document how to identify GIL contention.